# errors in VHDL code using fpga advantage

Tags: vhdl

I need your help in fixing some errors in my vhdl code. I am using fpga advantage 5.2, its too old, but I am using it because of block diagram, instead of writing the codes with myself.I am developing mips processor using vhdl, I have finished all the blocks except two blocks, which are data memory and instruction memory. Both blocks have the same errors:

Data memory errors:

> ERROR: C:/Single-cycle processor/Processor/hdl/dmem_untitled.vhd(34):
>   near "is": expecting: BEGIN ERROR: C:/Single-cycle
>   processor/Processor/hdl/dmem_untitled.vhd(51): near "process":
>   expecting: ';'

instruction memory errors:

> ERROR: C:/Single-cycle processor/Processor/hdl/imem_untitled.vhd(38):
>   near "is": expecting: BEGIN ERROR: C:/Single-cycle
>   processor/Processor/hdl/imem_untitled.vhd(53): near "process":
>   expecting: ';'

here is the code for the data memory:

```
-- hds header_start
--
-- VHDL Architecture Processor.dmem.untitled
--
-- Created:
--          by - Ahmed.UNKNOWN (AHMED-PC)
--          at - 01:58:50 04/21/2016
--
-- Generated by Mentor Graphics' HDL Designer(TM) 2001.5 (Build 170)
--
-- hds header_end
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.all;

use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_SIGNED.all;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.all;
use IEEE.std_logic_textio.all;
library STD;
use STD.textio.all;


ENTITY dmem IS
-- Declarations
 port(clk, we: in STD_LOGIC;
a, wd: in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0);
rd: out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0));

END dmem ;

-- hds interface_end
ARCHITECTURE untitled OF dmem IS
BEGIN
process is
    type ramtype is array (63 downto 0) of  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0);
    variable mem: ramtype;
    variable IADR: INTEGER;

    begin

    IADR:= CONV_INTEGER(a(7 downto 2));
    -- read or write memory
    --loop
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            if (we='1') then mem (IADR):= wd;
            end if;
        end if;
        rd <= mem (IADR);
        wait on clk, a;
    --end loop;
end process;

END untitled;
```

Also the code for the instruction memory :

```
-- hds header_start
--
-- VHDL Architecture Processor.IMEM.untitled
--
-- Created:
--          by - Ahmed.UNKNOWN (AHMED-PC)
--          at - 02:17:30 04/21/2016
--
-- Generated by Mentor Graphics' HDL Designer(TM) 2001.5 (Build 170)
--
-- hds header_end
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_SIGNED.all;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.all;

use IEEE.std_logic_textio.all;
library STD;
use STD.textio.all;



ENTITY IMEM IS
-- Declarations

  port(

     rd: out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 downto 0);
    a: in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(5 downto 0)
    );

END IMEM ;

    -- hds interface_end
    ARCHITECTURE untitled OF IMEM IS
    begin

    ROM_PROCESS: process(a) is
                                        type MEM is array(0 to 63) of STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 downto 0);
                                        variable MEMORY: MEM := (others => X"00000000");
                                        variable IADR: INTEGER;

    begin
            memory(0) := X"00611820" ; -- add $3, $3, $1
            memory(1) := X"ac030004" ; -- sw $3, 4($0)
            memory(2) := X"00221024" ; -- and $2,$1,$2
            memory(3) := X"10220001" ; -- beq $1, $2, SAME
            memory(4) := X"8c010004" ; -- lw $1, 4($0)
            memory(5) := X"0022182a" ; -- SAME: slt $3, $1, $2
            IADR:= CONV_INTEGER(a);
          rd <= MEMORY(IADR);

      end process;

    END untitled;
```

Answer (score 1):

The `is` in a process statement is optional from IEEE Std 1076-1993 forward but not allowed in the -1987 original revision of the VHDL standard.

Remove the `is` in both files following the process sensitivity lists. This tells us you are analyzing the VHDL with a -1987 compliant tool (for synthesis?).

Also note your use clauses are a mess.  Package numeric_std should never be used with Synopsys packages std_logic_arith or std_logic_unsigned.  You can simply comment out that use clause.

There's an implicit library clause making the library logical name `std` available, you don't need that. You aren't using textio either.

Your code would analyzes unchanged with a -1993 revision compliant VHDL tool.